# Mapping JSON columns Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, http, azure-data-factory

I'm trying to map the following request to an SQL database
https://api.exchangerate.host/timeseries?start_date=2023-01-01&end_date=2023-01-10&base=USD&symbols=MXN&format=json

The issue is that dates are constantly changing and I need somehow to map them with some sort of wildcard. I cannot use dataflows for this particular case.

[image]

At the end I need two custom columns with pre-defined integers, the date and the rate value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> At the end I need two custom columns with pre-defined integers, the date and the rate value

By using your request, I am able to get your requirement done using split and for loops and `openjson()`.

> The issue is that dates are constantly changing and I need somehow to map them with some sort of wildcard

As the dates are changing, you cannot access the values dynamically. To get it dynamically, first I have taken your request in a web activity and used a split on the string of `rates` object with `':{"MXN":'` with the below dynamic content.

`@split(string(activity('Web1').output.rates),':{"MXN":')`

I have stored this array in an array variable.

[image]

Then I have passed this array this ForEach by skipping the last value in it with below dynamic content.

`@take(variables('split_arr'),sub(length(variables('split_arr')),1))`

I am using this ForEach to build a JSON array with date and rate as objects in every index. For that I have used an append variable activity inside forEach to `json_arr` array variable with following dynamic content.

```
@json(concat('{"date":"',substring(item(),sub(length(item()),11), 10),'","rate":',activity('Web1').output.rates[substring(item(),sub(length(item()),11), 10)].MXN,'}'))
```

[image]

It will give the JSON array like below.

[image]

Use this JSON array with SQL as source to copy activity and use the `openjson()` in query like below.

```
declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'@{variables('json_arr')}';
SELECT date,rate FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (
date varchar(max),
rate decimal(8,6)
);
```

[image]

In sink of copy activity, give your sink as per your requirement. Here I have used an SQL table.

**This is my pipeline JSON for your reference:**

```
{
"name": "pipeline2",
"properties": {
    "activities": [
        {
            "name": "Web1",
            "type": "WebActivity",
            "dependsOn": [],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "url": "https://api.exchangerate.host/timeseries?start_date=2023-01-01&end_date=2023-01-10&base=USD&symbols=MXN&format=json",
                "method": "GET"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable1",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Web1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "split_arr",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@split(string(activity('Web1').output.rates),':{\"MXN\":')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "ForEach1",
            "type": "ForEach",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "items": {
                    "value": "@take(variables('split_arr'),sub(length(variables('split_arr')),1))",
                    "type": "Expression"
                },
                "isSequential": true,
                "activities": [
                    {
                        "name": "Append variable1",
                        "type": "AppendVariable",
                        "dependsOn": [],
                        "userProperties": [],
                        "typeProperties": {
                            "variableName": "json_arr",
                            "value": {
                                "value": "@json(concat('{\"date\":\"',substring(item(),sub(length(item()),11), 10),'\",\"rate\":',activity('Web1').output.rates[substring(item(),sub(length(item()),11), 10)].MXN,'}'))",
                                "type": "Expression"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Set variable2",
            "type": "SetVariable",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "ForEach1",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "variableName": "json_arr1",
                "value": {
                    "value": "@variables('json_arr')",
                    "type": "Expression"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Copy data1",
            "type": "Copy",
            "dependsOn": [
                {
                    "activity": "Set variable2",
                    "dependencyConditions": [
                        "Succeeded"
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "policy": {
                "timeout": "0.12:00:00",
                "retry": 0,
                "retryIntervalInSeconds": 30,
                "secureOutput": false,
                "secureInput": false
            },
            "userProperties": [],
            "typeProperties": {
                "source": {
                    "type": "AzureSqlSource",
                    "sqlReaderQuery": {
                        "value": "declare @json nvarchar(max) = N'@{variables('json_arr')}';\n\nSELECT date,rate FROM OPENJSON(@json) WITH (\n   date varchar(max),\n\trate decimal(8,6)\n);",
                        "type": "Expression"
                    },
                    "queryTimeout": "02:00:00",
                    "partitionOption": "None"
                },
                "sink": {
                    "type": "AzureSqlSink",
                    "writeBehavior": "insert",
                    "sqlWriterUseTableLock": false,
                    "tableOption": "autoCreate",
                    "disableMetricsCollection": false
                },
                "enableStaging": false,
                "translator": {
                    "type": "TabularTranslator",
                    "typeConversion": true,
                    "typeConversionSettings": {
                        "allowDataTruncation": true,
                        "treatBooleanAsNumber": false
                    }
                }
            },
            "inputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "AzureSqlTable1",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ],
            "outputs": [
                {
                    "referenceName": "targetsql",
                    "type": "DatasetReference"
                }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "variables": {
        "split_arr": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "json_arr": {
            "type": "Array"
        },
        "json_arr1": {
            "type": "Array"
        }
    },
    "annotations": [],
    "lastPublishTime": "2023-03-20T16:55:11Z"
},
"type": "Microsoft.DataFactory/factories/pipelines"
}
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Your answer has been really insightful. Due to time limitations I had to make a Python script but I will surely come back to this in a future.